# choose between two options without random number

Tags: java, branch

So, there are two branches and I want the program to choose only one of them randomly.

I know this can be done generating a random number and then depending on that number choose one of those paths (using if/else) but what I'm asking is if there's any other way to do this, any built-in function or more efficient option.

Comment: No. There is not. I you want randomness you need to use `Random`.

Comment: Basically everything ends up a number. I think a randomiser is the only way. Whats against random function?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "get random boolean". OP seems to know that that's an option, but he wants to do without a random number generator.

Comment: What about (arbitrary length read of /dev/urandom) % 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use current time as factor to make decision , so you have to take that hit but you can then use bit wise operation to decide branch

if(System.currentTimeMillis()&1==0) 
  .... 
else 
 ...........

bitwise is much more efficient as compared to %